# An array that recieves data in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I would like to have something like that into my array (it is an example) :

```
[Mercedes]
    [Classe A]
        [220 CV]
        [300 CV GTI]
        ...
    [Classe B]
        ...
```

The problem is that I have to use foreach to get this information and i'm not used to it.

Here is my code:

```
foreach($aResultat['Domaines'] as $iDomaineKey => $aDomaineValue){

    $aResultat['DomaineUnique'][$iDomaineKey] = $this->Domaines->find($aDomaineValue['DOMAINE_ID']);  // ID LIB DOMAINE
    $aData['Domaines'][$iDomaineKey] = $aResultat['DomaineUnique'][$iDomaineKey][0]['DOMAINE_LIB']; // LIB DOMAINE
    $aResultat['Lignes'] = $this->GrillesDomainesLignes->find($aParametresGrille, $aDomaineValue['DOMAINE_ID']);

foreach($aResultat['Lignes'] as $iLigneKey => $aLigneValue){

    $aResultat['LigneUnique'][$iLigneKey] = $this->Lignes->find($aLigneValue['LIGNE_ID']);
    $aData['Ligne'][$iLigneKey] = $aResultat['LigneUnique'][$iLigneKey][0]['LIGNE_LIB'];
}
```

Some information : 
`find` is a function that  can get anything from a table (`ID` or `ID` & `LIB` OF `Domaine` or `Ligne` in our case)

This is not working, I guess i'm not using the keys correctly.

$aResultat['Domaines] is like that :

```
    [Domaines] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [GRILLE_ID] => 1
                [1] => 1
                [DOMAINE_ID] => 1
                [2] => 1
                [ORDRE] => 1
            )

            ...
```

For DomaineUnique:

```
    [DomaineUnique] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                        [DOMAINE_ID] => 1
                        [1] => TOTO
                        [DOMAINE_LIB] => TOTO
                    )
                    ...
```

And for $aResultat['Lignes'] :

```
    [Lignes] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [GRILLE_ID] => 1
                [1] => 1
                [DOMAINE_ID] => 1
                [2] => 1
                [LIGNE_ID] => 1
                [3] => 1
                [ORDRE] => 1
            )
            ...
```

Domaine and Ligne are associative ones.
While DomaineUnique and LigneUnique are the real tables with my LIB into it.

My $aData return this :

```
$aDataArray
(
[Domaines] => Array
    (
        [0] => TOTO
        [1] => TOTO
        [2] => TOTO
        [3] => TOTO
    )

[Ligne] => Array
    (
        [0] => TATA
        [1] => TATA
        [2] => TATA
```

Comment: What result do you get from your current code?

Comment: what's the content of the arrays? `$aResultat['Domaines']` and `$aResultat['Lignes']`

Comment: what kind of output are u getting?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: I edited my code, and i'll read thoses subjects Riggs, thank you.

Comment: yes and whats your expected result from this array? or its a really } issue? as other mate shared in answer?

Comment: You can compare what I really have (aData) at the end of my post, and the exemple at the top which is what I would like to have

Comment: Ok, the problem is that i'm using [0] into $aData['Domaines'][$iDomaineKey] = $aResultat['DomaineUnique'][$iDomaineKey][0]['DOMAINE_LIB']; that's why i always have the first item in my aData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you've missed one `}`

```
foreach($aResultat['Domaines'] as $iDomaineKey => $aDomaineValue) {

    $aResultat['DomaineUnique'][$iDomaineKey] = $this->Domaines->find($aDomaineValue['DOMAINE_ID']);  // ID LIB DOMAINE
    $aData['Domaines'][$iDomaineKey] = $aResultat['DomaineUnique'][$iDomaineKey][0]['DOMAINE_LIB']; // LIB DOMAINE
    $aResultat['Lignes'] = $this->GrillesDomainesLignes->find($aParametresGrille, $aDomaineValue['DOMAINE_ID']);
} // This one!
foreach($aResultat['Lignes'] as $iLigneKey => $aLigneValue){

    $aResultat['LigneUnique'][$iLigneKey] = $this->Lignes->find($aLigneValue['LIGNE_ID']);
    $aData['Ligne'][$iLigneKey] = $aResultat['LigneUnique'][$iLigneKey][0]['LIGNE_LIB'];
}
```

Comment: No this is normal I guess, I wanted them to be nested.

Comment: I think `$aDomaineValue['DOMAINE_ID']` is undefined, cause `$aDomaineValue` is array like `Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [GRILLE_ID] => 1
                [1] => 1
                [DOMAINE_ID] => 1
                [2] => 1
                [LIGNE_ID] => 1
                [3] => 1
                [ORDRE] => 1
            )`